# How can I prevent EclipseLink/JPA doing a SELECT before every INSERT?

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

How can I prevent EclipseLink/JPA doing a SELECT before every INSERT?

The parent object in the example below is cached but every time a Child object is added it does a SELECT then a INSERT. The SELECT seems unnecessary as the Parent object is already cached.

My class def is below. The OneToMany is set to cascade ALL.

class Parent
    - List childern;

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Show us the code of the entities, and the code you're using to insert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EclipseLink does not perform a SELECT before every INSERT, and does enabled a shared cache by default.

Please include your code including what you are doing and the SQL log.

My guess is that you are using merge()?  With merge the object being merged can be new or existing, if it has a null id or 0 id (depending on config) it will be assume new and no select will occur.  If it has a non-null id and is new (not using a generated id), then a select will have to occur.  Consider using a generated id, or call persist() instead of merge().

If it is an existing object, then the current copy must be selected to know what has changed.  Normally it will be in the shared cache, and no select will occur.  If you have disabled the shared cache, or the object was never read on this machine, or expired from the shared cache, then a select will occur.